# condition Select query for db2

Tags: sql, db2, conditional-statements

Suppose there is a Table with 2 columns and the following data:

```
ID : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
DATA:a,a,a,a,a,a,a,b
```

There can be only one 1 row with DATA=b and multiple rows with DATA=a.

I need a query that will select only one row.If there is any row with DATA=b then we will select that and if there is no row with DATA=b then it will select the first row with DATA=a.

Please Help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * 
FROM  table
WHERE DATA in ('A', 'B')
ORDER BY CASE WHEN DATA= 'B' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, ID
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY
```

Comment: You are absolutely ignoring any other possibility for `DATA` other then 'a' or 'b'!